# Best Cursor use

Tags: android, android-cursor

I stumbled across many links on the use of a `Cursor` object but none about how it is **used best**.  So I have a couple of questions which I would really like answered.

- Is it okay to use one `Cursor` for all the application's database operations?  If no, why?
- Is it really necessary to keep opening and closing the `Cursor`s after every use?
- On [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) link the definition of `close()` is `Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it completely invalid.` What happens when it becomes invalid? Would it be re-usable?

Many thanks.

Comment: `1.` Cursor contains query results ... for every query you'll get new Cursor `2.` yes, it is necessary  `3.` invalid means invalid ... invalid Cursor can't be used or re-used ...

Comment: So why is it necessary to close the Cursor if it becomes invalid and thus un-usable?

Comment: to free resources ... you have the similar situation with Bitmap.recycle() ... internaly those APIs are written i C ... there is no GC there ... so you have to say explicitly: "i don't need it anymore"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.)Is it okay to use one Cursor for all the application's database operations? If no, why?

Yes. It is possible to re-use a cursor. However you should know that the working of a Cursor isn't as intuitive as you may think. The cursor doesn't fetch all data from some data store and store all of it in memory. Instead, it only fetches the data as required hence minimizing the memory use. So it is always a good idea to close the Cursor before re-initializing. That being said, there really isn't much performance penalty for creating a completely new Cursor every time you need one.

2.)Is it really necessary to keep opening and closing the Cursors after every use?

Yes, yes and yes. I once had a lot of problems debugging some network application which was to sync activities of the phone periodically to the local db then later send to an external server. Opening and closing (especially closing) is important just like any other stream or endpoint for communication in java or android e.g FileInputStream or Socket

3.)On this link the definition of close() is Closes the Cursor, reusing all of its resources and making it completely invalid. What happens when it becomes invalid? Would it be re-usable?

As I've said above, the close() method works just like most of the other close() methods of other classes in Java. Once you call it, you should not use the Cursor again. This is just like the Socket's class close() method. Once a Socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created.

Comment: Thank you linuxjava, this is the kind of answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

1.Every query returns a new Cursor. So you can use the same local cursor and reinitialize it with returned cursor

2.yes it is necessary to close every cursor. Because some unexpected error/force close can may corrupt your database it is open and also done to free the resources

3.invalid means invalid ... invalid Cursor can't be used or re-used  as Selvin sad

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to use cursor is to use loaders(cursorLoader in particular) take a look:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: Thank you, the link is very useful however it doesn't answer all of my questions.

Comment: All your questions will be answered as soon as you understand the cursor loader work and flow. It fully manages the cursor life-cycle.